# YAML - Jenkins Job builder

Tags: yaml, jenkins-job-builder

I need to tick checkboxes in Jenkins using Jenkins Job builder yaml projects. Attached is the snapshot from Jenkins

[image]

I need to put a tick in the checkbox and also select project Rule option in the radio button. How to do it in yaml?

Answer (score 0):

@Aditya: You can do this using **wrappers**: Below is the code I have used to enable `ci-skip` and `maks-passwords` in Jenkins UI.

`wrappers:
        - ci-skip
        - mask-passwords`

The above code will tick the checkbox besides `enable ci-skip` and `mask-passwords` in Jenkins UI.